# Azure B2C Self asserted screen with "continue" condition

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I want to add a screen where the users has to insert information. The "Continue" button should only be visible on conditions (like mandatory fields filled).
I have the self asserted screen in a Orchestration step and I can disable the continue button in general but not in dependency to claims.

Can someone send me some words I can search for? My google searches were not very successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use javascript to control the UI elements to achieve this.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-and-page-layout?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

Comment: okay, thank you. I implemented some javascript and disable the button in dependecy to form fields. After on, I also check the claims again in the User Journey so that it is not just "client side checked".

Comment: @Wyphorn do you have an example of what you have done?

Comment: Hi @fei0x,
I had a look for my policies, but it is to much for a comment. I will add this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

For everybody who needs an example:

```
  <ClaimType Id="extension_termsofuse_accepted">
    <DataType>string</DataType>
    <UserInputType>CheckboxMultiSelect</UserInputType>
    <Restriction>
      <Enumeration Text="I have read the Terms Of Use and accept them" Value="exampleDate"/>
    </Restriction>
  </ClaimType>

[...]

  <ContentDefinition Id="api.termsofuse">
    <LoadUri>myCustomURL.cshtml</LoadUri>
    <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
    <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:1.2.0</DataUri>
    <Metadata>
      <Item Key="DisplayName">Accept Terms of Use</Item>
    </Metadata>
  </ContentDefinition>
  
[...]

  <ClaimsTransformation Id="CreateTermsOfUseErrorMessage" TransformationMethod="CreateStringClaim">
    <InputParameters>
      <InputParameter Id="value" DataType="string" Value="You have to accept the Terms Of Use to login to your ID." />
    </InputParameters>
    <OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="errorMessage" TransformationClaimType="createdClaim" />
    </OutputClaims>
  </ClaimsTransformation>

[...]  
    <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-ShowTermsOfUse">
      <DisplayName>Terms Of Use</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.termsofuse</Item>
        <Item Key="setting.showCancelButton">false</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>     
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_termsofuse_accepted" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteProfileUsingObjectId" />
      </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
    
    <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-TermsOfUseError">
      <InputClaimsTransformations>
        <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateTermsOfUseErrorMessage" />
      </InputClaimsTransformations>
      <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="SelfAsserted-Error" />
    </TechnicalProfile>

[...]

    <OrchestrationStep Order="x" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>extension_termsofuse_accepted</Value>
          <Value>exampleDate</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="Accept-TermsOfUse" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-ShowTermsOfUse" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="x" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>extension_termsofuse_accepted</Value>
          <Value>exampleDate</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="EndLoginDueTermsOfUse" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-TermsOfUseError" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
```

In the end are the userjourney steps. First I compare user attributes to my policy. With this I check that the user has confirmed my Terms of Use in the current version. Everytime I update the ToU in significant way, I update my policy to a new date in the checker and the users will run into the condition of the first step. This guides the user to a website where he will accept the terms of use again in the new version. After on the new attribute value is stored to user account and condition of second steps is true now, so he skip error page. In case of bypass the Terms of Use new acceptance by some javascript hacks or something like that, the new value is not stored to user profile, so the condition of second step fails and the user run into an error page without exit. User has to stop the signin flow here with closing the browser tab and has to start to login.

Worked great for me.